# XP/level points in python game

Tags: python

so I am using this code:

```
def level():
lvl = 1
xp = 0 
lvlNext = 50

while xp >= lvlNext:
    lvl += 1
    xp = xp - lvlNext
    lvlNext = round(lvlNext * 1.5)

print ('level', lvl)
print ('Exp:', xp)
print ('Next:', lvlNext)

return
```

the only problem is that I am not sure how to apply the points the player can get into the action they chose to perform so for example:

```
elif choice== "use comb on hair":
    if "comb" in inventory:
        print ("You brushed your bald head. Satisfying.")
    elif "comb" not in inventory:
        print ("You don't own this item in your inventory.")
```

I a supposed to let the player get 15 points if they perform this, but I don't know how.

Comment: This is a very broad and more of a structural question with many possible solutions. Depending on How do you store xp? How are actions performed? Whats the general scope of your game? with multiple objects or simple sequential text?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the `+=` operator.

```
elif choice== "use comb on hair":
    if "comb" in inventory:
        print ("You brushed your bald head. Satisfying.")
        xp += 15
    elif "comb" not in inventory:
        print ("You don't own this item in your inventory.")
```

+= 
is a shortcut for writing:

```
xp = 1
xp = xp + 1
print (xp)   # 2
```

Comment: so I am not sure but this error occures when I put the xp+= 15

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'xp' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

Read up on classes, they'll come in handy.

Define:

```
class XPLevel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        XP = 0
    def (your function from the question):
        ...

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = XPLevel()

    def SomeActionWhatGivesXP(self, amount=1):
        self.level.XP += amount
```